# Android Studio - Asynctask get() freezes UI

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In Android Studio when I use `Asynctask`, execute it and try to use `get()` in the `onCreate` method it freezes my whole UI.

My Asynctask class:

```
public class HTMLDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
```

My onCreate method code:

```
    HTMLDownload task = new HTMLDownload();

    try {
        String result = task.execute("https://www.telltalesonline.com/26925/popular-celebs/").get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

     Log.i("Result", result);
```

How can I fix this and log the text once the HTML is downloaded without freezing the UI?

Thanks

Comment: don't use asynctask its deprecated. use any other threading mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned `AsyncTask` is deprecated. You are better off using something like [Android Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley)

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Inside your Fragment or class or whatever:

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
String url = "https://www.telltalesonline.com/26925/popular-celebs/";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // TODO handle the response
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO handle error
            }
        }
);

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```